# Shipping Charge Not working

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

In My site i used `getShippingDescription` but it's not fetching shipping price.

How to check and where to check for this method

```
    <?php $_order = $this->getOrder() ?>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<div class="page-title title-buttons">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Order #%s - %s', $_order->getRealOrderId(), $_order->getStatusLabel()) ?></h1>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('buttons') ?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getStatusHistoryRssUrl($_order) ?>
<dl class="order-info">
    <dt><?php echo $this->__('About This Order:') ?></dt>
    <dd>
        <?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
        <ul id="order-info-tabs">
        <?php foreach ($_links as $_link): ?>
            <?php if($_link->getUrl()): ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a></li>
            <?php else: ?>
                <li class="current"><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($('order-info-tabs').select('LI'),['first','last']);</script>
    </dd>
</dl>
<p class="order-date"><?php echo $this->__('Order Date: %s', $this->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), 'long')) ?></p>
<?php if (!$_order->getIsVirtual()): ?>
<div class="col2-set order-info-box">
    <div class="col-1">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-title">
                <h2><?php echo $this->__('Shipping Address') ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content">
                <address><?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress()->format('html') ?></address>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-title">
                <h2><?php echo $this->__('Shipping Method') ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content">
                <?php if ($_order->getShippingDescription()): ?>
                <?php echo $_order;?>
                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingDescription()) ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('No shipping information available'); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="col2-set order-info-box">
    <div class="col-1">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-title">
                <h2><?php echo $this->__('Billing Address') ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content">
                <address><?php echo $_order->getBillingAddress()->format('html') ?></address>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <div class="box box-payment">
            <div class="box-title">
                <h2><?php echo $this->__('Payment Method') ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content">
                <?php echo $this->getPaymentInfoHtml() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where you are using it?

Comment: Customer view order page

Comment: I don't think where this method is written

Comment: what is full code can you paste that?

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: you want to display the shipping  charges?

Comment: Yes i want to display the shipping charges it doesn't display anything

Comment: did you load the $_order?

Comment: this only problem it shows billing address and shipping address also

Comment: can you paste full code?

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: if condition is working or going to else condition?

Comment: if condition it shows Shipping - Charges : this only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this                     `<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingDescription()) ?>`

with

```
    $orderSymbolCode = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($_order->getOrderCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();

$_order->getShippingDescription().' '.$orderSymbolCode.''.number_format((float)$_order->getShippingAmount(),2, '.', '');
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getOrderCurrencyCode()

Comment: my mistake updated code try now

Comment: mail also it will work

Comment: i will work as far as you know what you are doing :D

Comment: @QaisarSatti could you pls help me -> How can i apply extra shipping charge for only selected products sku? -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/238570/57334